# Wiring a custom cassandra cluster config to a repo class during runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

> **I have the following classes:**

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepoDC1 extends CassandraRepository<MyBean, String> {
 ...
}

@Repository
public interface MyRepoDC2 extends CassandraRepository<MyBean, String> {
 ...
}


@EnableCassandraRepositories(cassandraTemplateRef = "myRefTemplateDc1", basePackages = "com.test.repodc1")
@Configuration
public class CassandraDC1ClusterConfig {
 ...
}

@EnableCassandraRepositories(cassandraTemplateRef = "myRefTemplateDc2", basePackages = "com.test.repodc2")
@Configuration
public class CassandraDC2ClusterConfig {
 ...
}
```

> About the classes:

- Both MyRepoDC1 and MyRepoDC2 have the same member variables.
- CassandraDC1ClusterConfig has a connection to a data-center named dc1.
  CassandraDC2ClusterConfig has a connection to a data-center named dc2.

> **Current scenario:**

I am using MyRepoDC1 to insert data into the DB. If I incur an exception during runtime, I am resorting to a fallback method that uses MyRepoDC2 to save the data.

> **My Query:**

Is there a way to create the connection that uses CassandraDC2ClusterConfig during runtime and wire it to the MyRepoDC2 (or something similar)? In my current scenario, **2 connections are being created unnecessarily during start-up, which is a costly operation**. I am trying to avoid that.